# AJAX issues (Cannot get ajax to successfully work) PHP, AJAX, JAVASCRIPT, WORDPRESS (NO PLUGIN)

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I asked a question earlier today with little luck:
[AJAX within a foreach loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25705398/ajax-within-a-foreach-loop)

i was put on the right path but the answer provided has got me more confused than ever.
Whenever i click on my anchor tag with the ajax call, nothing happens. When i go into console view and check the network tab, it says the call was a success. when i go further into the call details it shows all the data i sent and the page it went too. The code on page_id=252 does not fire whatsoever.

I am using wordpress for this assignment.
I am using custom templates to hold my PHP code. not a plugin.

I have two pages:

```
Index.php
ajaxcall.php
```

**Index.php** (?page_id=## is default permalinks to my wp pages. this location is valid.)

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function onClickingThis(rem_opt,vidid){
      $.ajax({
          url: '?page_id=252', 
          type: 'POST',
          data: {action: 'update_this_func', remove_option: rem_opt, uservideo_id: vidid },
          dataType: 'json',
          success: function(response){
            console.log('works');
          }
      });
    }
</script>

// all my php code, for everything on the page.
<a href="#"  onclick="onClickingThis(0,1)></a>
```

**ajaxcall.php**

```
function update_this_func(){
$remove_option = $_POST['remove_option'];
$uservideo_id  = $_POST['uservideo_id'];

global $wpdb;

$wpdb->query("UPDATE " . $wpdb->prefix."uservideo
              SET is_removed =" . $remove_option . "
              WHERE uservideo_id =" . $uservideo_id );

return json_encode(['status' => 'Updated!']); // return status as json
}
```

This code was provided by user: Ervald, but he did not want to elaborate on his code.
My success message is not working for the ajax, but i am not getting any errors in the console.
How do i debug my ajax? is my ajax not set up properly? If this is not the right way to use ajax please let me know. Any help is **GREATLY** appreciated.

Comment: You can debug AJAX looking for XHR items on Chrome's Network tab, in Developer Tools (F12). Click on the item and it will show another frame on your right, you may then look to request's info as well the "preview" tab.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there have been 2 problems in your `PHP` script:

1. the function was not called

2. the return-value of the function was not echoed.
*(in order to respond to an `AJAX` call, the called `url` always needs to output something - `JSON` in the most cases. `AJAX` can't access `PHP`and thus can't read `PHP` return values.)*


here is the fixed version:

```
function update_this_func($remove_option, $uservideo_id){

    global $wpdb;

    $wpdb->query("UPDATE " . $wpdb->prefix."uservideo
                  SET is_removed =" . $remove_option . "
                  WHERE uservideo_id =" . $uservideo_id );

    return json_encode(['status' => 'Updated!']); // return status as json
}
echo update_this_func($_POST['remove_option'], $_POST['uservideo_id']);
```

Comment: Thank you so much.
it has been a long day, wasn't even aware that the arguments were not provided to the function.

Comment: @user3753569 well, they have been defined inside the function with the values of the `$_POST` vars. which also works, cause `$_POST` vars are global and therefore also accessible inside functions. so this wasn't the problem. i for myself just like it more this way, that's why i changed it.

Comment: @user3753569 and you're welcome :)  if you could upvote my question as well, you would do me another favor ;)