# How to get data from AJAX in PHP without using a function

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, wordpress

**NOTE: No more down-votes please, just because you cannot answer the question/ or cannot understand the problem doesn't mean you have to down-vote. I clearly said I can provide more information/be more specific if you need me too.**

**Edited title for clarification**

I am using javascript to validate the form client side, then using ajax to pass 3 arrays worth of data to a separate PHP page for processing. Just trying to perform a basic query with one of arrays before i begin.

the ajax request says it's working, and when I go into the network tab, then click response, it shows all the arrays with the correct values/indexes.

But on the PHP side nothing is happening. I have no idea how to debug the PHP because it's on a different page. I'm assuming this has something to do with my syntax, as I have got this too work before, but i used ajax in a function. I am very new to ajax, so I am not too sure if I am doing this correctly. I have tried a valid `$wpdb` query on the page and nothing is happening. How do i properly structure my PHP page to work with the ajax? Any way I can debug my PHP when ajax fires?

If you need additional information please let me know.

**AJAX CALL:**

```
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "?page_id=251",
data: { vData: videoData, tsData: tsValues, dData: tsDescriptions},
success: function(){
$("#errorMessage").text("ajax success.");
}});
```

**?page_id=251  (PHP page)**

```
 <?php
 $videoData = $_POST['vData'];    // i have also tried $_GET['vData'];
 $vSRC = $videoData[0];$vTIT = $videoData[1];$vDES = $videoData[2];$vPDF = $videoData[3];$vDAT = $videoData[4];  
 $uID = get_current_user_id();

 global $wpdb;

 $wpdb->insert( $wpdb->prefix."uservideo", array(
               "user_id" => $uID,
               "video_src" => $vSRC,
               "video_title" => $vTIT,
               "video_description" => $vDES,
               "pdf_file" => $vPDF,
               "video_date" => $vDAT
            ));

 ?>
```

Comment: Your URL says `?page_id=251`. You are aware that this will post to index.php/index.html, and be doing a weird combination of a GET/POST request? I don't think this is what you want. You probably intend to be referencing an actual file...

Comment: I am using wordpress which permalinks pages. that is a valid local, if i change it too: ?page_id=fkdjkfhdsfk, the ajax doesn't work.
On my other ajax call i used same syntax and it works. Now that i am not using a function my PHP isn't working with ajax data.

Comment: You are not correctly implementing Ajax, this not what WordPress recommends. You should read the [Intro to Ajax](http://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX) or jump right into [Ajax in plugins (just ignore the word plugins here)](http://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins)

Comment: I have to use custom pages, no plugin.
 And it's a simple ajax call. The ajax call wouldn't work at all if it wasn't implemented correctly. The issue is grabbing the data and working with it on PHP.

Comment: here are the docs, http://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins please try some things and ask a more specific question when you're ready

Comment: @user3753569 Did you read the docs before commenting?

Comment: @andrew Not using a plugin.

Comment: @RahilWazir Yes I did, I also tried using the methods provided, it works the same as my ajax call, but the PHP does not do anything, like i said over and over. Do I have to print my array values first, like i did for ajax function call? here is question i asked that got an answer : http://stackoverflow.com/q/25706618/3753569

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to the issue.
I needed to call a function with the ajax, cannot just call a page. I'm sure you can just call the page but no one knows how apparently.

**AJAX**

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function insert_data(vidData,timesData,descData){
      $.ajax({
          url: '?page_id=251', 
          type: 'POST',
          data: {action: 'insert_video', vData: vidData, tsData: timesData, dData: descData },
          dataType: 'json',
          success: function(response){
            alert('dhsdhjsdjhsjhdjhsd');
          }
      });
    }
</script>
```

**PHP**

```
<?php
function insert_video($videoData,$tsValue,$tsDesc){
 $videoData = $_POST['vData'];
 $vSRC = $videoData[0];$vTIT = $videoData[1];$vDES = $videoData[2];$vPDF = $videoData[3];$vDAT = $videoData[4];
 $tsValue = $_POST['tsData'];
 $tsDesc = $_POST['dData'];
 $uID = get_current_user_id();

 global $wpdb;

 $wpdb->insert( $wpdb->prefix."uservideo", array(
               "user_id" => $uID,
               "video_src" => $vSRC,
               "video_title" => $vTIT,
               "video_description" => $vDES,
               "pdf_file" => $vPDF,
               "video_date" => $vDAT
            ));
}
 echo insert_video($_POST['vData'], $_POST['tsData'], $_POST['dData']);
?>
```

Comment: Why do you have extra `action: 'insert_video'` data now? This is what written in the docs. You need to post the `action` data as well. With same `action` value method on PHP side.

Comment: Action: is used to specify which function is being called. And it doesn't matter if i use WP ajax or a normal AJAX, same thing. I am trying to not use a function and just call the page, but I don't think you can do that with ajax.